# How to work out bits required for addressing memory?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

I can't understand how to solve this problem. This problem is related to operating systems.

> Consider a virtual address space of 4GB with physical memory up to 64MB.
>
> (a) How many bits do you need for a physical memory address?
>
> (b) How many bits for a virtual address space?

How do I work out how many bits are required?

Answer (score 1):

The number of bits needed to address `n` locations is `log2n`.

In other words, two to the power of *what* will give you `n`?

For `64M`, that's `64 x 1024 x 1024`, or `26 x 210 x 210`, or `226`<sup><sup>(note a)</sup></sup>. So twenty-six bits are required.

The larger `4G` value is `4 x 1024 x 1024 x 1024`, or `22 x 210 x 210 x 210`, or `232`. So thirty-two bits are required.

---

<sup><sup>(note a)</sup></sup> In case you're wondering, the expression `na x nb` is equivalent to `n(a+b)`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!